# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I keep getting this error whenever I try to delete the image file from the firebase storage:

> Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference

I recently updated all the firebase packages and since then I am not able to delete images from firebase Storage

Folder in FirebaseStorage
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Code to delete the file.

```
deleteApartments(
   PersonalApartment personalApartment, Function apartmentDeleted) async {
      if (personalApartment.imageUrl != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < personalApartment.imageUrl.length; i++) {
     Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('/apartment_images')
        .child(personalApartment.imageUrl[i]);

         await storageReferences.delete();
        }
    } else {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('apartments')
         .doc(personalApartment.id)
           .delete();
      apartmentDeleted(personalApartment);
   }

        FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('apartments')
        .doc(personalApartment.id)
        .delete();
        apartmentDeleted(personalApartment);
        print('images deleted');
 }
```

Debuge Console

```
     2I/System.out(11910): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
     E/StorageException(11910): StorageException has occurred.
     E/StorageException(11910): Object does not exist at location.
     E/StorageException(11910):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
     E/StorageException(11910): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": 
    "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
     E/StorageException(11910): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 
    404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": 
    "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
     E/flutter (11910): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] 
     Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object 
     exists at the desired reference.
```

Images of the folder in firebase storage
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: I have edited the question format.